# How to fill fields base on another field in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have one template with 2 forms: `Entregaform` and `EnderecoEntregaForm`. 
When `Entrega` is equal `"Entregar na Empresa"` I have to fill the fields from `EnderecoEntregaForm`. 
When `Entrega` is equal to `"Retirar no Cartório(Centro/Barra) - Gratuito"`, I don´t have to fill the fields from `EnderecoEntregaForm`.
How can I do that in **Django**?

[image]

Comment: So do you want your EnderecoEntregaForm to auto populate the fields once the "Entregar na Empresa" option is selected? Or do you just want the EnderecoEntregaForm to be displayed when "Entregar na Empresa" is selected and hidden when the "Retirar no Cartório(Centro/Barra) - Gratuito" option is selected?

Comment: When "Entregar na Empresa" is selected the fields from EnderecoEntregaForm are Required. When "Entregar na Empresa" is not selected the fileds from "EnderecoEntregaForm" are not Required.

Comment: All the logic must be done in your backend, when you submit the form

Comment: Try looking at this tutorial: https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/creating-conditionally-required-fields-in-django-forms/577/